# How to remove Document Type in Xcode 13 Info

Tags: xcode, plist

I'm trying to remove an extra document type I accidentally added in the info project settings. I can't seem to remove it. I've opened the plist and removed it from there, but it keeps getting added back in automatically. Anyone know how to do this correctly?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Same here, and the text of the fields is literally being rendered upside down!

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, I solved it by opening the Info.plist, removing the unwanted types, then immediately quitting Xcode.
Then, restart XCode and reopen the project, the unwanted types are gone.

Comment: Helped me while being on Version 14.2 (14C18).

Answer (score 2):

You have to reopen the project. It worked for me